# A formula number field can't be used in rollup summary

Tags: formula-field, master-detail, roll-up-summary

The child object has two formula number field and when I want to create a rollup summary field on parent object, one of them is not available.

What can be the reason of it?

Comment: You can’t use long text area, multi-select picklist, Description fields, system fields like Last Activity, cross-object formula fields, and lookup fields in the field column of roll-up summary filters. Can please check the other formula field is referenced from other object or not?

Comment: The field uses another object's field in it's formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formula fields can only be used in a rollup summary if they are idempotent (in other words, if they return the same value every time when the record is not edited). This means you can't use cross-object formulas, or formulas that depend on TODAY() or NOW(). This is noted in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=5):

> If a roll-up summary field doesn’t contain cross-object field references or functions that derive values on the fly, such as NOW or TODAY, it can calculate the values of formula fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer: "...However, as the formula field is referring to a field in another object (e.g. cross object reference), it is not available for use."

source: https://focusonforce.com/configuration/salesforce-roll-up-summary-using-the-value-of-a-formula-field/